# Fortran polymorphism in pointers

Tags: class, pointers, fortran, polymorphism

I am trying to use pointers to create links between objects. Using Fortran and here is the code piece:

```
 module base_pars_module
   type,abstract,public :: base_pars
   end type
 end module 
 module test_parameters_module
   use base_pars_module
   type, extends(base_pars) :: test_pars
     contains 
     procedure :: whoami
   end type
   contains
   function whoami(this) result(iostat)
     class( test_pars) :: this
     write(*,*) 'i am a derived type child of base_pars'
   end type
 end module
 module base_mask_module
   use base_pars module
     type, abstract , public :: base_mask
     class(base_pars),pointer :: parameters
   end type
end module
module test_mask_module
  use base_mask_module
  implicit none
  type, extends(base_mask) :: test_mask
  end type
end module
program driver
type(test_pars) , target :: par_Test
type(test_mask) :: mask_test
  iostat= par_test%whoami()
  mask_test%parameters=>par_test
  iostat=mask_test%parameters%whoami()
end program
```

`parameters` at `base_mask_module` is a pointer with `base_pars` class. I would like to use this pointer to refer `par_test` object which is `test_pars` type that extends `base_pars` type. So the pointer and the target has the same class. But when I compile this it gives an error:

```
 driver.f90:17.37:

iostat=mask_test%parameters%whoami()
                                  1
Error: 'whoami' at (1) is not a member of the 'base_pars' structure
```

Is it a bug or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: This code can't compile, though.  You're missing some `use`s in the main program.

Answer (score 7):

When you have polymorphism like this there are two things to consider about an object: its *dynamic* type and its *declared* type.  The `parameters` component of `test_mask` (`base_mask`) is declared as

```
class(base_pars),pointer :: parameters
```

Such a component therefore has declared type `base_pars`.

Come the pointer assignment

```
mask_test%parameters=>par_test
```

`mask_test%parameters` has dynamic type the same as `par_test`: `test_pars`.  It's of declared type `base_pars`, though, and it's the declared type that is important when we care about its components and bindings.  `base_pars` indeed has no `whoami`.

You need, then, something which has declared type `par_test`.  Without changing the definitions of the derived types you can do this with the `select type` construct.

```
select type (pars => mask_test%parameters)
class is (par_test)
  iostat=pars%whoami()  ! pars of declared type par_test associated with mask_test%parameters
end select
```

That said, things get pretty tedious quite quickly with this approach.  Always using `select type`, distinguishing between numerous extending types, will be quite a bind.  An alternative would be to ensure that the declared type `base_pars` has a binding `whoami`.  Instead of changing the main program as above, we alter the module `base_pars_module`:

```
module base_par_modules
  implicit none  ! Encourage good practice

  type,abstract,public :: base_pars
   contains
    procedure(whoami_if), deferred :: whoami
  end type

  interface
    integer function whoami_if(this)
      import base_pars    ! Recall we're in a different scope from the module
      class(base_pars) this
    end function
  end interface

end module
```

So, we've a deferred binding in `base_pars` that is later over-ridden by a binding in the extending type `test_pars`.  `mask_test%parameters%whoami()` in the main program is then a valid and the function called is that offered by the dynamic type of `parameters`.

Both approaches here address the problem with the binding of the declared type of `parameters`.  Which best suits your real-world problem depends on your overall design.

If you know that your hierarchy of types will all have enough in common with the base type (that is, all will offer a `whoami` binding) then it makes sense to go for this second approach.  Use the first approach rather when you have odd special cases, which I'd suggest should be rare.

Comment: As a loose guideline (valid exceptions exist) use of select type is a symptom of a problem with the underlying type hierarchy, particularly if all the code is doing is calling a binding of the selector (in which case you have dynamic dispatch through select type to invoke dynamic dispatch through the binding).  It completely depends on what the OP is trying to do, but a more appropriate solution may be to move the `whoami` binding into the base type as a deferred binding.  At least some sort of qualification should be attached to the use of select type in this answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I've hopefully covered your comment.  On reflection I should indeed have gone for the more general point initially.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @francescalus but deferred binding is not a solution here. What I was trying to do is to establish connections between objects of the same class. Function 'whoami' was just an example. I wanted all objects which inherits 'base_mask' object has a pointer of the class 'base_pars'.

Comment: @dundaryilmaz I'm afraid I may be mis-understanding your question, but when you have a component pointer of declared type `base_pars` (as in the question), then you cannot reference a binding of that component which isn't in the declaration of `base_pars`.  Regardless of its dynamic type.  If you want the component of `test_mask` to have declared type `test_pars` (for example) then you'll have to declare it as such rather than relying on the dynamic type being `test_pars`.  (Unless you use the `select type` construct.)

Comment: @francescalus well I tried to do this as with class concept. Since base_pars and test_pars has a parent-child relationship, declared pointer with parent class/type should work with child class/type. I believe other OO languages work in this way.

Comment: @dundaryilmaz I don't see what is confusing you: perhaps you could edit the question, or even ask a new one (referencing this one), rather rely on the constraints of comments?  You seem to be saying that you expect an object of type `base_pars` to have a binding `whoami` even when that is declared only in extending types of that type.  Or is it that you don't see why `mask_test%parameters` is of (declared) type `base_pars` rather than `test_pars`?