# unlimited polymorphic class pointing to a child (extended declared type) in Fortran

Tags: oop, linked-list, fortran, polymorphism, intel-fortran

I am trying to make a data tree structure with features that mimic the linked list kind of thing using polymorphism in Fortran. Each box or object has a pointer to its children and one to its parent, both pointers of same object type. Because I thought of a having a reference to the root of data tree structure I initially define a declared type as follows:

```
type r_oct 
    integer :: max_depth 
    class(*), pointer :: root 
end type
```

Then, I extends this to another type which contains the main attributes of this data structure

```
 type, extends(r_oct) :: element_oct 
     rea                        :: pts
     type(element_oct), pointer :: parent 
     type(element_oct), pointer :: children(:)
 end type
```

Now I wanted to have two different constructors so I declare following

```
  interface r_oct
     module procedure              :: INIT_r_oct
     module procedure              :: INIT_element_oct
  end interface r_oct
```

In my function `INIT_r_oct` I simply have

```
  function INIT_r_oct( max_depth ) result( oct )

  implicit none

  class(r_oct), pointer     :: oct
  integer, intent(in)       :: max_depth

  if( associated(oct) )then
     print*, "ERROR, called more than once"
     stop
  else
     allocate(oct)
     nullify(oct% root)
     oct% max_depth = max_depth
  endif
  end function INIT_r_oct
```

Everything sofar is good. But now the following function is where I got the problems.

The Idea is that I want to keep the root pointer pointing to the first instance of the `parent` pointer of the child object, namely, `element_oct :: parent`

```
  function INIT_element_oct (this, pts ) result( ele_oct )

  class(r_oct), pointer, intent(inout)  :: this
  real, intent(in)                      :: pts
  type(element_oct), pointer          :: ele_oct

  allocate(ele_oct)
  this%root => ele_oct
   this%root%parent%pts = 1 ! this does not work


  end function INIT_element_oct
```

It complains that the `this%root` does not have the parent attribute, as if it does not do what I intend `this%root => ele_oct`

I am bit new to this way of programming in Fortran, So I am guessing that something is not fully understood by myself, I hope you can come up with some better suggestions to what i am trying to do.

**UPDATE**

So it seems that `select type` might help me out.

In function `INIT_element_oct` I do this instead:

```
function INIT_element_oct (this, pts ) result( ele_oct )

class(r_oct), pointer, intent(inout)  :: this
real, intent(in)                      :: pts
type(element_oct), pointer          :: ele_oct

allocate(ele_oct)
this%root => ele_oct
select type ( aux => this% root) 
type is (element_oct) 
   aux = ele_oct%parent ! this now works!!!
end select
end function INIT_element_oct
```

But is `this%root` now really pointing to ele_oct%parent?, i.e. if you later on want the pointer to the very first element, can I use the root pointer to get, because it seems like this is a temporary pointing to it.

Is there a way to use the `deferred` type to solve this

**Calling from Main program**

```
  program TEST_OCT
  use mod_oct

  implicit none

  class(r_oct), pointer      :: first
  class(element_oct), pointer :: octree

  integer                       :: i,j, max_d

  max_d = 10

  first => r_oct(max_num_point)
  oct => r_oct(first, 1.0)
```

Comment: Do not make fenctions that return pointers. Ever. Just don't. Constructors should return normal `type()`.

Comment: `this%root` is unlimited polymorphic and so has no components.  You'll probably want to read up on declared/dynamic types, `select type`, etc., and refine the question with something more specific (such aspects of polymorphism are likely too broad to be covered in a single question).

Comment: @VladimirF, should the function just be defined as 

`type(class_name) function INIT_element_oct(this, pts) ` ?

Comment: @A2LBK I do not see the purpose of the `this` argument.

Comment: @francescalus, yes I am defining this%root as unlimited polymorphic because at time of declaration the child classes have clearly not been defined. I am not sure how the `select type` will help me. My question is simply how I can point the `this%root` to another object as I am trying here  : `this%root => ele_oct`

Comment: @VladimirF, So you advise not to have the class/type as argument  i.e 

`function INIT_element_oct ( pts ) result( ele_oct ) `

Comment: You can have `this%root` point to `ele_oct` and it gains the _dynamic_ type `element_oct` which has a component `parent`.  However, to reference `this%root%parent` requires `this%root` to have a component `parent` in its _declared_ type.  `this%root` has no declared type.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you exactly mean. Am I not pointing `this%root` to `ele_oct` by `  this%root => ele_oct`. And when that gains the dynamics type of `element_oct` why can't I then reference the parent attribute which is an attribute of `element_oct`

Comment: See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31220961/3157076) for some of the concepts.

Comment: I looked at it. I get the feature of the deferred attribute. But I really don't understand how the `select type` can help. Is that not only used to check what type of the unlimited class is, whether that is a certain object or some integer, real etc. 

How will that help with my case ?

Comment: Not only it checks, but then it makes the variable to be of that particular type within  the block and not polymorphic.

Comment: Ohh Thanks, I did not realize this before now. Although, I am still struggling to realize whether the thing I am trying to do is possible or not.
1) Is it possible with the `select type`, then if it is possible to give me an example using the example above.

2) Is it possible with the `deferred` attribute, and again will greatly appreciate an example if it also works with that.

Comment: btw, you say whiten the block, so outside the `select type` it returns to an unlimited polymorphic

Comment: Do you mean `aux%parent => ele_oct%parent`?

Comment: I mean if `this% root => ele_oct%parent`. I set `aux=> this% root` in `select type` only because the fortran compiler where complaining that I need to assign an associated variable to `this% root`
So essentially, yes `aux%parent => ele_oct%parent`.
but aux's scope is only within the block, right?

Comment: The scope of `aux` is the construct, but it's associated with `this%root` so changes to `aux` affect `this%root` also.  It's much the same as with the dummy and actual arguments of the subroutine: `this` has scope of the subroutine only, but changes to `this` affect whatever the argument to the subroutine is.

Comment: Makes sense, But Im still not working out how I can the root pointer pointing to the first instance of the child declared type.
Is no one really not able to clarify whether possible, or not, and in case how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of *how you want to* **call** the function `INIT_element_oct` once written? Because I fail to understand the `this` argument. If the constructed instance is `ele_oct`, why would it be the root of a passed instance `this`?

Comment: I provided the example. I am not sure if that is the way to do it. What I try to do is to have a pointer which always points to the first element of the list. So I declare the this as the parent class and try to point it to a pointer in the child class.