# Problem with accessing child declared type in Fortran

Tags: class, oop, fortran, intel-fortran

Consider the following code

```
  module class_type

  implicit none
  class(*), pointer :: fnzo => null()


  type, abstract :: gen

     real :: ss
     integer :: sdsd
     class(gen), pointer    :: next =>null()
  end type

  type, extends(gen) :: final1

     real :: ss1

  end type final1

  type, extends(gen) :: final2

  real :: x1(10)

  end type


  end module class_type



  program test_class

  use class_type

  implicit none

  class(gen), pointer :: test
  type(final1) :: test1
  allocate(test, source = test1)

  print*, test% ss1




  end program
```

I am trying to work out a a linked - list where each next element either inherits `final1` or `final2`. Currently, just testing simple cases and I don't understand why I cannot access  `test%ss1`. Anyone to help

Comment: `test` is of declared type `gen` which has no component `ss1`.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31220961/3157076) is heavily related.

Comment: _Why_ you can't `print *, test%ss1` is because of the lack of component `ss1` in type `gen`.  However, the other part of your question about how to access the "dynamic component" will depend somewhat on _how_ you want to do this access.  Can you explain what design goals you have so that we can be precise in our answer?

Comment: What I actually want to do is  to have a base type like `gen`. On run time I will build a linked list with either `final1` or `final2`. Those two latter objects are two separate children of the same parent i.e. the `gen`. As a result,  what I want is for example something like... 
start%final1%final2%final2%final1 .. the alternating between final1 and final2 can be arbitrarily,. The importance is that each final1 and final2 always have at least the members of the parent namely `gen` and then specific members deepening on the child type. Does this make sense?

Comment: Once you've got something like `start%next=>test; test%next=>test2`, etc., you're just wondering how to work out what type a particular element in the linked list is?  Then you can "do this if of type final1" or "do this if of type final2"?  In which case, you may find `select type` is all you need.  There will be lots to read here on that topic.

Comment: I know that `select type` can be useful and I was even thinking to have a `deferred procedure` which returns the class, kind of whoami thing. BUT that is not my Problem. 
My test cannot access the base members, those from `gen` - even though `test` is a child created from `gen` - and that is what my question is about.

Comment: When I create a child, whether final1 or final2, I would like to inherit all members of their parent all the time. But now it seems that I cannot do that?

Comment: You do inherit all the members of the parent type.

Comment: but Why can't I access them? when I try to access `test% ss1` it fails to compile even when I declare `test` as `class` and allocate it with the source referring to which child I want?

Comment: `ss1` is not a member of the parent type...

Comment: Then what is the whole point of saying `allocate(test, source = test1)` here I mean the bit with `source = test1`.

Comment: What is the most elegant way to make the allocation without being explicit in the declaration. As Ideally I want in the routine check if the next object shall be test1 or test2

Comment: `allocate(test, source = test1)` makes the variable `test` of _dynamic_ type `final1`.  However, as in the linked answer, that doesn't allow you to access `test%ss1` because that requires `test` to be of _declared_ type `final1` (it remains of declared type `gen` regardless of anything you do to it).

Comment: Are you aware of an elegant solution to this - given I described what I ultimately want with it

Comment: @francescalus and what is the point of having a _dynamic_ type of `final1` when it does inherit its members?

Comment: I dont know if we both use the word "inherit" in the same meaning. Anyway, I think you are missing something very basic about *dynamic dispatch*. This is the single most important concept of OOP and the reason why bother with type extension and type bound procedures. Without understanding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch properly, especially the purpose, *not just the mechanics*, we can't get much further. The point is to have subroutines of some abstract type and be able to call them without knowing the exact dynamic type of the object and the implementation of that subroutine.

Comment: @VladimirF I in fact use the abstract interfaces a lot to avoid all if statements and basically just call the procedure pointer which has been declared with an abstract interface. 
What I don't understand is why we would necessarily do `allocate(test, source = test1)`, when the `test` cannot access members from `test1`.
Is the reason the following:
If we would have had deferred procedures in `test` and we allocated with `source=test1` that we by this invocation imply that these deferred procedures would now be overloaded with those in `test1` ??

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Ask why is `test` declared with the type it is declared. Why is it declared the parent type and not the child type? Is it necessary or a good decision? Sometimes it is and then you have to use `select type` immediately after the allocation. But you need a *specific reason* for using the parent type as the declared type even though you know you will be using some particular child type.

Comment: @VladimirF the whole purpose behind my question has been laid out. So,  I would appreciate if what you write about can be reflected on what I am trying to do. If I am approaching this totally wrong from the beginning, then I am here to learn this.

Comment: That's what I am quite hard trying to do, actually. You are now asking about how language works and also why and that cannot be done without tackling program design. You can't just talk about syntax, because that is a tool, that is sometimes handy but sometimes a wrong thing to use. So when you ask why you cannot do something the answer can be you are not supposed to do that unless you have a particular good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for "why we cannot access `test% ss1`", the following code might be useful for considering the reason. In this code, I get a user input (`inp`) and determine whether `ptr` points to variables of type `test1` or `test2`. If `ptr` points to a variable of `test2`,  accessing `ptr% ss1` is clearly meaningless, so the compiler needs to guard against such an incorrect access. I think that is why the compiler allows only the access of components of `gen` (= declared type) unless `select type` (for actual data in memory) is provided.

```
program test_class
  use class_type
  implicit none
  class(gen), pointer  :: ptr    !! parent type
  type(final1), target :: test1  !! child type
  type(final2), target :: test2  !! child type
  integer :: inp

  print *, "input some integer"
  read *, inp

  if ( inp == 1 ) ptr => test1
  if ( inp == 2 ) ptr => test2

  print*, "ptr% ss = ", ptr% ss   !! OK

  ! print*, "ptr% ss1 = ", ptr% ss1  !! error (Line1)

  select type ( ptr )
    type is ( final1 ); print*, "ss1 = ", ptr% ss1  !! OK
    type is ( final2 ); print*, "x1  = ", ptr% x1   !! OK
  endselect

end program
```

If the Line1 is uncommented, it gives an error (with gfortran-8)

```
   print*, "ptr% ss1 = ", ptr% ss1  !! error
                             1
Error: 'ss1' at (1) is not a member of the 'gen' structure; did you mean 'ss'?
```

I guess the situation is similar to other (statically typed) languages. For example, the following code in C++ gives an error when we access `ptr->b`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    int a = 1;
};
struct B : A {
    int b = 100;
};

int main() {
    A *ptr;
    ptr = new B;
    cout << ptr->a << endl;     // 1
    // cout << ptr->b << endl;  // error: 'struct A' has no member named 'b'
    delete ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access `ss1`, you need a pointer within your abstract class to the child object. The pointer can be of either type extensions you wish to define. Since your linked list has two different type extensions, you are required to declare two child pointers within your abstract class.

```
module class_type

  implicit none
  class(*), pointer :: fnzo => null()


  type, abstract :: gen

     real :: ss
     integer :: sdsd
     class(gen), pointer    :: next =>null()
     type(final1), pointer  :: child
  end type

  type, extends(gen) :: final1

     real :: ss1

  end type final1

  type, extends(gen) :: final2

     real :: x1(10)

  end type final2


end module class_type



program test_class

  use class_type

  implicit none

  class(gen), pointer  :: test
  type(final1), target    :: test1

  allocate(test, source=test1)

  test1% ss1 = 20.0
  test% child => test1

  write(*,*) test1% ss1

  write(*,*) test% child% ss1

end program test_class
```

When you compile and execute, you'll see:

```
   20.00000    
   20.00000
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow.  If you don't know whether an item in the linked list should be considered to be of type `final1` or of type `final2`, then how do you know whether to dereference the component with type `final1` or that with type `final2`?

Comment: Then I think you can do it with functions/subroutines and interfaces.