# Issues with type bound procedure in an array of polymorphic elements

Tags: fortran

I am updating a bit of code with new features and ideally my solution would include an array where every element is of a different type, which is not possible as such in fortran. So I tried to use an array of polymorphic objects, but got stuck at the point where after initializing the array elements I can't seem to call any of the type bound subroutines.

Here is a gist of the problem.

Type declaration module:

```
type :: fruit
end type fruit

type, extends(fruit) :: apples
contains
procedure :: init => init_apples
end type apples

type, extends(fruit) :: oranges
contains
procedure :: init => init_oranges
end type oranges

contains

pure subroutine init_apples(me)
class(apples), intent(inout) :: me

! Do Stuff

end subroutine init_appples

pure subroutine init_oranges(me)
class(oranges), intent(inout) :: me

! Do Stuff

end subroutine init_oranges
```

In the main program then:

```
use apropriate module

type fruit_basket
  class(fruit), allocatable :: item
end type

type(fruit_basket), allocatable :: gift(:)

allocate(gift(2))

!Option 1
allocate(apples::gift(1).item)
allocate(oranges::gift(2).item)

!Option 2
gift(1) = fruit_basket(apples)
gift(2) = fruit_basket(oranges)
```

compiler accepts either of the above options. Now ideally I would like to call the init for one of those elements

```
!Tried this
call gift(1).init()

!Also tried this
call gift(1).item.init()
```

either of these produces an error:
error #6460: This is not a field name that is defined in the encompassing structure.   [init]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

So I kind of gotten it to work, not really happy with how it works, but I suppose it will do:

Type declaration:

```
Module type_declaration

  implicit none

  type, abstract, public :: Base_Type
  contains
  procedure(init_base), deferred :: init
  procedure(get_base), deferred  :: GetResult
  end type

  interface
  pure subroutine init_base(this, x)
  import Base_Type
  class(base_type), intent(inout) :: this
  real(8), intent(in) :: x
  end subroutine

  real(8) pure function get_base(this)
  import Base_Type
  class(base_type), intent(in) :: this
  end function

  end interface

  type, extends(Base_Type) :: Subtype1
    real(8) alpha
  contains
  procedure :: init => init_type1
  procedure :: GetResult => get_res_type1
  end type

  type, extends(Base_Type) :: Subtype2
    real(8) alpha, beta
  contains
  procedure :: init => init_type2
  procedure :: GetResult => get_res_type2
  end type

  contains

  pure subroutine init_type1(this, x)
  class(Subtype1), intent(inout) :: this
  real(8), intent(in) :: x

  !Work here
  this.alpha = x * 2.

  end subroutine

  pure subroutine init_type2(this, x)
  class(Subtype2), intent(inout) :: this
  real(8), intent(in) :: x

  !Work here
  this.alpha = x * 2
  this.beta  = x / 3.

  end subroutine

  real(8) pure function get_res_type1(this)
  class(Subtype1), intent(in) :: this

  get_res_type1 = this.alpha

  end function

  real(8) pure function get_res_type2(this)
  class(Subtype2), intent(in) :: this

  get_res_type2 = this.alpha + this.beta

  end function  

  end module type_declaration
```

Main program Variant 1:

```
    program Polymorhic_Test

    use type_declaration

    implicit none

    type data_container
      class(Base_type), allocatable :: item
    end type

    type(data_container) :: MainArray(2)

    real(8)        :: x, y = 0.
    character(10)  :: cDummy

    allocate(Subtype1::MainArray(1).item)
    allocate(Subtype2::MainArray(2).item)

    x = 1.
    call MainArray(1).item.init(x)
    y = MainArray(1).item.GetResult()

    x = 2.
    call MainArray(2).item.init(x)
    y = MainArray(2).item.GetResult()

    read cDummy

  end program Polymorhic_Test
```

Main Program variant 2

```
program Polymorhic_Test

  use type_declaration

  implicit none

  type data_container
    class(Base_type), allocatable :: item
  end type

  type(data_container) :: MainArray(2)

  real(8)        :: x, y = 0.
  character(10)  :: cDummy
  type(Subtype1) :: ST1
  type(Subtype2) :: ST2

  x = 1.
  call ST1.init(x)
  allocate(MainArray(1).item, source=ST1)
  y = MainArray(1).item.GetResult()

  x = 2.
  call ST2.init(x)
  allocate(MainArray(2).item, source=ST2)
  y = MainArray(2).item.GetResult()

  read cDummy

  end program Polymorhic_Test
```

I will probably go with option 2, just because I then don't have to defer init in base type, because my sub types will have different number of parameters needed for init and I don't like the idea of having base type init with 20 something optional parameters.

Comment: `gift(1)` is of declared type `fruit_basket` and `gift(1)%item` is of declared type `fruit`, neither of which has a type-bound procedure `init`.  If you don't understand those aspects then we can possibly find related questions.

Comment: Consider for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31220961/3157076).

Comment: @francescalus thanks for the link to the question. Unfortnatelly that was exactly what I was trying to avoid. The idea was to have extending types with their own set of (potentially not overlaping) subroutines and parameters. But if I have to defer the whole mess in the base type, it kind of makes the whole less attractive. I mean it makes sence, how should compiler know what extending type I'm referring too. I was under impression that there was a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a linked list implementation like in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/n-s-k/de4af7ce6cc8f2c85e4b33cedb51fd88#4-case-study-data-polymorphic-linked-list) (section 4 and 5).

However in your case you probably still can't avoid a `select type` statement.

Comment: One does not really need a linked list, there were plenty of examples here on StackOverflow, how to use arrays of a wrapper container.